# Matching Hashed and Salted Passwords from Database

Tags: java, authentication, shiro, sha256

I have built a custom realm using Apache Shiro to account for our application having more than one location for user accounts and stored passwords. Originally I was using Shiro to hash and match the passwords, but the custom realm means I have to do some of these things manually.

After looking I came across this code:

```
public String sha256(String base) {
    try{        
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        byte[] hash = digest.digest(base.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();

        for (int i = 0; i < hash.length; i++) {
            String hex = Integer.toHexString(0xff & hash[i]);
            if(hex.length() == 1) hexString.append('0');
            hexString.append(hex);
        }

        return hexString.toString();
    } catch(Exception ex){
       throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
```

I added a salt and it works great, so I'm wondering if I can just store the returned value in a database when creating a username\password pair and then later retrieve it to match the provided password (plus the salt). That seems like it should work, but when I did this previously with Shiro the SHA256 password hasher did NOT return the same value with the same base password each time, yet it was able to always match it. I wanted to make sure I'm following a valid (and most importantly secure) methodology for handling passwords.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things:
You can create a hash of a string buy using something like: `new Sha256Hash(password, salt)`

Take a look at [this example](https://github.com/apache/shiro/tree/master/samples/spring-hibernate)

If you have multiple places your users are stored, you should probably have a different realm for each store .